# two and three-way interactions in a mixed within-between design

Tags: interaction, anova

I have two groups of subjects, both undergoing two experimental conditions, and data are collected at three time points. I am interested in the time*cond and the time*cond*group interactions. When I don't include the group*time interaction, the three-way interaction is significant. However, when the non-interesting group*time interaction is included in the model, the three-way interaction is no longer significant.

Why does this happen and which analysis is correct?

Comment: Do you have equal n?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

It is almost never correct to include a three way interaction without including all the two way interactions that are part of it. So, you want to include it.  You also don't want to get too hung up on significance.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought but I was confused about the fact that the F for the three-way interaction dropped sharply when the adding a significant two-way interaction. Why does that happen?